# Change color if repeated record

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

What formula can I use to change the color of the font when the sames value already appears previously in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the field you try to check if it has a previous match (for example ID)

```
{ID} = previous({ID}) Then crRed Else crBlack
```

Hope it works

Comment: Huh, that's not a bad idea. I suppose it only works if the records are sorted such that duplicates appear next to each other, but if that's the case this is much simpler than what I suggested!

Comment: Works Great ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try first making a running total that keeps a Distinct Count of the field. Place this in your details section. Then write a *whileprintingrecords* formula to check whether or not your distinct count matches the Previous one. (Except for the first record, of course. You might need to make a special case for that.)

In theory, every time this second formula evaluates to false, a repeated record is added.

---

If that doesn't work, you could always declare an array that adds each new type of record to its ranks, and sets a shared boolean to false/true based on whether or not the current record already exists in the array.